# jq add lines to existing file using bash

Tags: json, bash, sh

I created a .sh script to configure an Ubuntu 16.04 server.
The final part I need to include is to add lines to the existing file /etc/docker/daemon.json in order to move the Docker log files to the journal.

The line is:

{
  "log-driver": "journald"
}

I did some research and found that jq can probably do the job.
However, I am not sure of the exact syntax I should use within the .sh script.

Comment: We need to see `/etc/docker/daemon.json` to help you.

Comment: Agreed. Please share your json file as well as what you want it to look like after jq does its work.

Comment: AND there is no need to include a 600 line config file in your Q. Reduce the sample config to the smallest subset that shows the top level elements and just enough sub-levels to get to where you want `"log-driver"` inserted. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks.  To clarify, the original /etc/docker/daemon.json file is blank.  I just need to add that one line.

Comment: `echo '{ "log-driver": "journald" }' > /etc/docker/daemon.json` ? Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.